# Django - Query on overridden save() method cached or something

Tags: python, django

I am overriding the default save() method of my model in Django 4.
The problem is that I am making queries related to an instance of the model with the overridden save() method, but the queries seem not to be updated during the method execution.

Example:

```
class Routine(models.Model):

    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        e = self.exercises.all()  # 3 exercises returned
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # I call to super deleting 1 exercise and adding a new one
        e = self.exercises.all()  # same 3 exercises returned, not updated with the previous save() call
```

Once all the code has been executed the routine.exercises have been properly updated, the problem is that I am not being able to get this query updated during the save() override.

Comment: Have you read about the speciality of m2m relations? This „save“ cant work. You have to use .set or .add or .remove to manipulate the m2m objects properly

Comment: I tried testing this and it is not cached. Also, according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#all), the `all` method would invalidate the cache in any case. My guess is, the m2m relation is not deleted properly. Can you add the code where you add the m2m relation?

Comment: maybe try use `self.refresh_from_db()` before query exercise again?